# Get All images in the DOM using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have a load of images in the DOM, where the images href is set in CSS.

Anyone know a fairly good way to pull out a list of all of these much like

```
document.images
```

This pulls out an array of image tags.

I need to do a similar thing but pull out all image urls that might be located in CSS Classses

I need to do a replace on certain images using JavaScript

Comment: You mean you want to get all the images which have a class which is in css?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can:

1. Loop through the stylesheet objects in [`document.styleSheets`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/styleSheets)
2. For each stylesheet (a [`CSSStyleSheet`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet)), loop through its `cssRules` (old IE uses `rules` rather than `cssRules`)
3. For each rule (a [`CSSRule`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSRule)) that has a `style` property, loop through that style object's properties and, of those that are strings and have the target image, do your replacement.

Example replacing my Gravatar with yours after one second:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  var rexOldImage = /ca3e484c121268e4c8302616b2395eb9/g;
  var newImage = "fe10f9831fc5d88da31dab172740a1ad";
  var slice = Array.prototype.slice;
  slice.call(document.styleSheets).forEach(function(styleSheet) {
    slice.call(styleSheet.cssRules || styleSheet.rules).forEach(function(rule) {
      var name, style;
      if (rule.style) { // Only CSSStyleRules have a style prop
        for (name in rule.style) {
          style = rule.style[name];
          if (typeof style === "string" && rexOldImage.test(style)) {
            rule.style[name] = style.replace(rexOldImage, newImage);
          }
        }
      }
    });
  });
}, 1000);
```

```css
.some-class {
  background-image: url(https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ca3e484c121268e4c8302616b2395eb9?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG);
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="some-class"></div>
```

If that use of `slice` is unfamiliar, see the "array-like objects" part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476).

Comment: I have picked one of the style sheets document.styleSheets[0].rules[0];
 and the rules text is "@import url("layout.css");"

Comment: @WelshKing: I suspect you'll find the styles from the imported sheet either as a separate sheet object, or as rules in that same sheet object. Sadly, `cssText` is read-only, so we have to work harder -- see the updated answer.

Comment: perfect solution - couldn't explain it better :)

Answer (score 0):

You could ajax load the css file in javascript with a get call then use regex matching to find the urls in the css. You would want to dedupe too incase of duplications but that's also possible.

Let me know if you need code to help.